# reading from a pipe -- stateful or stateless

Tags: python, linux, pipe

I need to write a python script that processes the output of a another program. i.e. I have to do:

```
./other_program | ./my_scripts.py
```

My question is whether this `my_script.py` is `state-less`. For example can I remember the last line of output I processed that came out of `./other_program`, or the script will only process current line, completely unaware of last line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipes don't know about "lines". Bytes go in on one end, and the same bytes in the same order come out at the other end. There is a little bit of (configurable) buffer in between, but when working with them, consider them being unbuffered.

And line oriented I/O happens at a higher level, e.g. when creating a C stdio `FILE` object on a pipe file descriptor, or using a *readline* library (or similar). Or – like in your case – Python stdio `print`, `writelines` and `readline`.

*EDIT 1:*

Here are two simple python programs

---

`writer.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
if '__main__' == __name__:
    import time
    i = 0;
    while True:
        print(f'This is writer.py, writing a line number {i} to stdout', flush=True)
        i += 1
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

---

`reader.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
if '__main__' == __name__:
    i = 0
    while True:
        l = input()
        print( f'This is reader.py, a line number {i} was read from stdin with the following content\n> {l}\n' )
        i += 1
```

---

Test them with `./writer.py | ./reader.py`

Comment: Interesting,  I thought `my_script.py` would be invoked whenever a new "line" came, but I guess my understanding is incorrect. In this case `./my_scripts.py` is just always running and processing the stdin?

Comment: @MattFrank: Yes exactly. When you `|` two programs in a shell what happens is, that the stdout of the first program is directly connected to the stdin of the second.